# How to show user's correct guesses in Hangman (Ruby)

Tags: ruby

If the user guesses a correct letter, I want it to show the exact place. Like this: word banana. User writes "a" and it shows _a__a_a

```
word = nil      #no word or letters yet
tries = 0       #setting the tries to zero
letter = nil    #no word or letters yet

puts "This is a game for 2. Player 1 writes which word they want player 2 to guess."
puts "Player 1, write a word: "
word = gets.chomp
letters = []
letters = word.split(//)
progress = ["_ " * letters.length]
puts progress
puts "Player 2, guess a letter: "

while tries < 10 || letters.length == 0
    letter = gets.chomp
    if letters.include? letter
        ind = letters.index(letter)
        progress.insert(ind, letter)
        progress.delete("_ ")
        letters.delete(letter)
        puts "You guessed one letter!"
        progress = "_ " * letters.length
        puts progress
    else
        puts "Nope, sorry."
        tries += 1
        puts "You have " + (10 - tries).to_s + " left"
    end
end
```

Comment: What is the logic for determining the number of underscores in `_a__a_a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some modifications to the main loop so that you can check if the player won:

```
def check_and_print(letters, guessed)
  won = true

  # Print letters accordingly
  letters.each do |l|
    if guessed.include? l
      print l
    else
      print '_ '
      won = false
    end
  end

  # Insert a line break
  puts ""

  return won
end

while tries < 10 || letters.length == 0
    letter = gets.chomp
    if letters.include? letter
        puts "You guessed one letter!"
        guessed << letter
        won = check_and_print(letters, guessed)

        # Check if the user won
        if won
          puts "You won!!"
          break
        end
    else
        puts "Nope, sorry."
        tries += 1
        puts "You have " + (10 - tries).to_s + " left"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be something like this:

```
def show_progress(word,guessed_letters)
  display_string = ''
  word.chars.each do |char|
    if guessed_letters.include?(char)
      display_string << char
    else 
      display_string << '_'
    end
  end
  display_string
end
```

Then you just call this with the answer and the letters guessed so far

```
show_progress('duck', ['u','k','f'])
# => "_u_k"
```